# Error installing virtualenvwrapper on windows

Tags: python, windows, git, python-2.7, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to setup virtualenvwrapper in GitBash (Windows 7). This is what it looks like:

```
1 $ export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
2 $ export MSYS_HOME=/c/msys/1.0
3 $ source /c/Python27/Scripts/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

On the third line I used /c/Python27/Scripts/virtualenvwrapper.sh instead of /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh because my virtualenvwrapper.sh file was located in /c/Python27/Scripts. When I try to run the third line it says this:

```
path = C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/virtualenvwrapper-initialize-hook-XXXXXX XXXX   
lpPathBuffer = C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ 
szTempName = C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp23A9.tmp 
path = C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp23A9.tmp 
fd = 3 
ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not create a temporary file name.
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

A great answer for this question is https://stackoverflow.com/a/28522399.

It seems to have been fixed in version 4.4.0 of virtualenvwrapper (as of [this commit](https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper/commits/7a8a268652423f7cdbecc8ac905aeb89235a86ac)).